# utf8_encode difference between result in SQL and PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, utf-8

I'm using utf8_encode to make sure that the input from my users is transforming the special characters to a character where my MYSQL can do a search on. (My database is set in latin1_swedish.ci).

When I echo my query, I get a perfect query that I can run against my MYSQL (and I get an result). But when I do the same query via my PHP it doesn't work.

```
$name = 'Widerøe';
$name = utf8_encode($name);

SELECT id FROM type WHERE name = '$name' LIMIT 1
SELECT id FROM type WHERE name = 'WiderÃ¸e' LIMIT 1

$data = mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT id FROM types WHERE name = '$name' LIMIT 1"));
$operator_id = $data['id'];
```

Comment: It seems like you have only put the query in your PHP, that's not how MySQL works in PHP. Here's a tutorial: https://www.mysqltutorial.org/php-mysql

Comment: I think I excecute the query correctly, I added it to my original thread!

Comment: if you encode a string that is already in utf8, you're destroying it...

Comment: I don't understand, the value in the database is WiderÃ¸e instead of Widerøe. Thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found a (easy) fix. I removed the utf8_encode and placed the following meta tag in the head of my body.

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1"/>
```

Comment: You nowhere mentioned HTML in your question and this (avoiding UTF-8 at all) should be the answer?